# unexpected unindent

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как исправить unexpected unindent?

```py
except:
time.sleep
```

Comment: Добавить перед `time.sleep` 4 пробела

Comment: только умерев..

Answer (score 2):

Отступы имеют значение

```py
...
except:
    time.sleep(1)
...
```